# Function invocation quota limits for us-central1... deprecated?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-billing

I was happy to learn I can set limits to my function invocations so I don't have to worry about billing. I tested it and it works (by setting the limit to 0). But:

1. Why does it say deprecated? I couldn't find documentation on this anywhere.
2. What's the alternative? Should I even be using this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was sent via email with the subject **Some GCF Quotas will be removed on Sept 8, 2020**

Some customers may have used quotas as a way to limit spending, e.g., either via the default quota limits or by lowering their quota. You should now be advised to use [Cloud Billing Budgets](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets#budget-scope) or [Max Instances](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances) to limit spending or usage.

For further details, feel free to report your issue on [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: What is GCF? Google Cloud Functions?

Comment: @AskYous indeed